# By what information are applications grouped in Windows Taskbar

Tags: wpf, windows, taskbar

I have a WPF application that has two builds, one is `beta` and another is `stable`.

The user can have both of them installed at the same time, each within its own folder in `%localappdata%` (`%localappdata%\app-name` and `%localappdata%\app-name (beta)`.

When they are both installed at the same time, Windows groups them on the taskbar as if being the same application.

So, the apps are not binary-equal, they reside in different directories and they do not have the same title. But there's obviously a piece of information that's shared between the two apps which is what Windows uses to determine how to group the apps, but I don't know what piece of information that is.

**What is that piece of information** which I need to **change** for one of them so that they can be **properly distinguished** by Windows in order for **each to have its own** taskbar item?

Answer (score 0):

The GUID in assembly info:

You should create a different GUID for each version
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-7.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The taskbar grouping is based on the [Application User Model IDs (AppUserModelIDs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids). If you don't specify one then Windows will generate one for you using undocumented details.

You can p/invoke `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID` to set a specific one for the whole process. It is also possible to set one per window.